# Interpreting the Y values of a normal distribution

Tags: pandas, dataframe, histogram, normal-distribution

I've written this code to generate a normal distribution of a set of values 1,2,3 :

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3]})
print(df)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
df.plot(kind='hist', normed=True, ax=ax)
```

Returns :

[image]

The X values are the range of possible values but how are the Y values interpreted ?

Reading http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/normal.htm the Y value is calculated using :

> A normal distribution has a bell-shaped density curve described by its
> mean   and standard deviation  . The density curve is symmetrical,
> centered about its mean, with its spread determined by its standard
> deviation. The height of a normal density curve at a given point x is
> given by [image]

What is the meaning of this formula ?

Comment: The [probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is formally a derivative of the cumulative distribution function (CDF), so the PDF is a derivative of the probability.  You have to integrate (get the area) to get a probability.  Intuitively, the PDF is a measure of the probability intensity.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204420/understanding-probability-density-functions and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing two concepts here. A histogram will just plot how many times a certain value appears. So for your list of `[1,2,3]`, the value `1` will appear once and the same for `2` and `3`. If you would have set `Normed=False` you would get the plot you have now with a height of 1.0.

However, when you set `Normed=True`, you will turn on **normalization**. Note that this does not have anything to do with a normal distribution. Have a look at the documentation for `hist`, which you can find here: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist
There you see that what the option `Normed` does, which is:

> If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., n/(len(x)`dbin), i.e., the integral of the histogram will sum to 1. If stacked is also True, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.

So it gives you the formula right there. So in your case, you have three points, i.e. len(x)=3. If you look at your plot you can see that your bins have a width of 0.2 so dbin=0.2. Each value appears only once for for both `1`, `2`, and `3`, you will have n=1. Thus the height of your bars should be 1/(3*0.2) = 1.67, which is exactly what you see in your histogram.

---

Now for the normal distribution, that is just a specific probability function that is defined as the formula you gave. It is useful in many fields as it relates to uncertainties. You'll see it a lot in statistics for example. The [Wikipedia article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) has lots of info.

If want to generate a list of values that conform to a normal distribution, I would suggest reading the documentation of `numpy.random.normal` which will do this for you: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Comment: thanks I did confuse two concepts. A set of values that follow the bell curve when normalized using Normed=True can be interpreted as a normal distribution ? I think the answer to this question is yes because if we normalize values and those values form a bell curve then further scaling those values to > 0 and < 1 will form a normal distribution ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If your set of values comes from a normal distribution, then the histogram will represent a bell curve. With normed=True, the total area of all the bars (width*height) will add up to one. Similar to how the integral over the Bell curve is one.